# async button in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net

so basically im in a process of creating my unit project which is an eCommerce website. one of the feature that important is a watch list (ex: watch list in ebay)

now i already finish in designing and succeed in adding/removing db record but what bothers me is that the page is the delay/ page posting back for each item saved/clicked. i tried adding an update panel but there is a still delay when we click the button.

below is my copy of the code

Design

```
<listview>
   <itemTemplate>
   ...... 
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
          <ContentTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSaved" class="btn-icon btn-white btn-star btn-radius" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="ToggleSave">
                   <span></span>
                   <asp:Label ID="lblSaved" runat="server" Text="Save Activity" AssociatedControlID="lnkSaved"></asp:Label>
                 </asp:LinkButton>
          </ContentTemplate>
          <Triggers>
                 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkSaved" />
          </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    .......
    </itemtemplate>
</listview>
```

CodeBehind

```
protected void ListViewActivities_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
         HiddenField hdnisSaved = e.Item.FindControl("hdnisSaved") as HiddenField;
         HiddenField hdnActivityID = e.Item.FindControl("hdnActivityID") as HiddenField;
         LinkButton lnkSaved = e.Item.FindControl("lnkSaved") as LinkButton;
         Label lblSaved= e.Item.FindControl("lblSaved") as Label;
         Guid userID = new MembershipHelper().GetProviderUserKey(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);

         if (Convert.ToBoolean(hdnisSaved.Value))
         {
             lnkSaved.Attributes.CssStyle.Clear();
             if(Convert.toboolean(hdnisSaved.Value))
               { 
                  lnkSaved.Attributes.Add("Class", "btn-icon btn-white btn-radius btn-star");
                  lblSaved.Text ="Save";
                }
             else
                {
                  lnkSaved.Attributes.Add("Class", "btn-icon btn-white btn-radius btn-starred");
                   lblSaved.Text ="Saved";
                }
             new CustomerDAC().ToggleSave(userID,      Convert.ToInt32(hdnActivityID.Value,hdnisSaved.Value));
         }
}
```

could you guys give me a direction, what should i do so a user will have a smooth experience(async prefered) when clicking this button.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to perform the action on the client side (browser side) in javascript/jquery and then sync the changes in the background, so that the user's perception is immediate but the slow part (http roundtrip to the server and persisting the data to DB) happens in the "background".